# Why does not display:block and 100% width work on table rows?

Tags: html, css

Table rows that have `display: block` are unable to get 100% width of the parent table, when they have `display: table-row` they naturally get 100% width but that CSS value has some other side effects which I try to avoid at the moment.

[Plunker that demonstrate the problem.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ms3IIGpslx5FfzTU0lvb?p=preview)

What causes table rows to act like this and not like normal block level elements?

Comment: Did you try adding display block on tbody?

Comment: Yep, but that kind of reverses the problem and the rows with display: table-row won't get 100% width. I am curious to the root issue of this, not just a "patch".

Comment: why do you need it? its define already as a table..

Comment: @Riskbreaker Because you can't set height on display: table-row (which complicates my animations), and also because I am interested in what actually causes this, not just a work around.

Comment: Ah cool ok makes sense now

Comment: Well, for one thing, the block boxes don't have a proper formatting context to participate in other than the same one that the table itself lives in. Trying to change the display property of any internal table elements will more often than not result in unexpected behavior, even if that behavior is well-defined.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This behavior has to do with how are tables treated on browsers.

The `table` element is set as `display:table`. The `tr` is a `display:table-row`, and the `td` is `display:table-cell`. It works the same if you are creating a div based css table.

On this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rv4v2964/1/, I've created the same basic example, but with divs instead, and added a `block` element nested to the table, but off any row or cell.

You can notice that it stays limited to the first cell's width. One reason is stated in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/):

> ...the table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells...

Meaning that when an element is odd to the table structure, the first cell's width set the value for the entire column. This is actually a `table-layout` behaviour specified on W3:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout

> ...a cell in the first row with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property determines the width for that column...

Another article mentions different behaviors on each browser on how to threat elements that are off the table structure. http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

**CONCLUSION**

Browsers don't like when you create table, and place inside it elements that are not supposed to be there. It is likely to be rendered wrongly. It will take in count the first cell's width as its parameter.

On this specific case, a workaround may be setting the display as `display: table-caption;` that takes the whole width of the table. Then, setting the property `caption-side` as `bottom`, it will stay in the bottom of the table.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/rv4v2964/2/

Reference: http://www.tagindex.net/css/table/caption_side.html

Answer (score -2):

Simply put the table in div with class "table-responsive" like this

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table"></table>
</div>
```